# I'm creating a little sound that plays when your mouse hovers over the button "White team" but nothing really happens. I'm using the MouseEnter event

Tags: user-interface, uibutton, roblox, mainmenu

I have been trying to create a sound every time your mouse leaves and enters this button. The code doesn't really work. I have tried this on a local script and a normal script:

````
script.Parent.MouseEnter:Connect(function()
    local sound = script.Parent.Parent.hit
    sound:Play()
    
end)

script.Parent.MouseEnter:Connect(function()
    local soundTwo = script.Parent.Parent.hitS
    soundTwo:Play()

end)
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5niz4.png -- The explorer of the game (I used script and local script btw and none of them changed anything, but i do think local script would work better for a gui)
````

Comment: I think this is a Roblox issue and nothing to do with your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following lines at the top of your code.

```lua
if not sound.IsLoaded then sound.Loaded:Wait() end
if not soundTwo.IsLoaded then soundTwo.Loaded:Wait() end
```

Also, both of your functions are for `MouseEnter`. Try changing one to `MouseLeave`.

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work if i have the script as a button's child. I fixed it by having the script's parent the same as the button's parent. But thanks!